# A relation between the intersection of two nonzero principal ideals and the zero ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

For an integral domain $D$, we have $\langle a\rangle\cap \langle b\rangle\neq 0$ for every nonzero elements $a,b \in D$,

Now in a general case, let $R$ be a commutative ring with 1, such
that $R$ has no nontrivial idempotent. I am looking for a
general condition (other that $0$ is an irreducible ideal)  for $0$
(the zero ideal) under which $\langle a\rangle\cap \langle b\rangle\neq 0$ for all nonzero
element $a,b \in R$.

Comment: If you *must* use something other than parens for principal ideals, please use \langle and \rangle and not angle brackets

Comment: Cross-posted: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/232949/a-condition-like-primeness-for-zero-ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that we have a ring $R$ with the property that, for each $0 \neq a, b \in R$, we have $(a) \cap (b) \neq (0)$.

Now suppose we have two ideals $0 \neq I, J < R$.  Pick some element $0 \neq a \in I$ and some element $0 \neq b \in J$.  Since $(a) \cap (b) \neq (0)$, there exists some $0 \neq c \in (a) \cap (b) \subseteq I \cap J$.  That is, $I \cap J \neq (0)$.

So this condition is in fact equivalent to $0$ being an irreducible ideal.  [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_ring), this condition on a ring is called *irreducibility*, or *meet-irreducibility* in the non-commutative case.